# Phpunit not working, says "PHP Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? on line 277"

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpunit

I've just installed Laravel and PHP on my new computer.

I've setup phpunit to work in :memory:

On running

> phpunit

I get:

> PHP Warning:  "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break".
>   Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in
>   E:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php on line 277
>
> Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you
>   mean to use "continue 2"? in
>   E:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php on line 277 PHP Warning: 
>   "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to
>   use "continue 2"? in E:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php on
>   line 285
>
> Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you
>   mean to use "continue 2"? in
>   E:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php on line 285 PHPUnit
>   3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.

phpunit.xml environment variables are setup to:

```
<server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
 <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
 <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
```

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 4.00Mb

No tests executed!

But I expect the test to run!

Comment: A simple Google [Backward Incompatible Changes PHP7.2 -> 7.3](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration73.incompatible.php)

Comment: I had the same issue and the linked thread doesn't answer the asked question.  The issue is probably that you are running the wrong version of `phpunit`.  To run the version that is installed in your project, run `vendor/bin/phpunit` or `vendor/bin/phpunit.bat`.  The test should then run successfully.